# Where shall we let the community update Xcode download locations?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, clean-up, external-links

A reminder of a common close reason (bold from me):

> **Questions asking us to** recommend or **find a** book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Extracting the bold words, I read:

> Questions asking us to find a tool are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Yet:

- [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file?rq=1) top answer is updated regularly<sup><sub>*</sub></sup>, question was [closed by me and community on Apr 8 '17](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10335747/timeline), deleted by community, undeleted by a moderator.
- [Download & Install Xcode 10 version without Premium Developer Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-10-version-without-premium-developer-account) has both the question title and the top answer updated regularly, [close review invalidated three times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44390162/timeline).
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions has the question tags and an answer updated regularly, despite being closed by the community
- [Xcode Download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529782/xcode-download) has the question tags and an answer updated regularly, [close review invalidated once](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19529782/timeline)
- [Downloading Xcode from somewhere other than the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240275/downloading-xcode-from-somewhere-other-than-the-app-store) has the question tags and an answer updated regularly, [close review invalidated twice](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10240275/timeline).
- [Where is the download link for Xcode for developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014598/where-is-the-download-link-for-xcode-for-developers?rq=1) was attempted to be updated regularly, until a moderator deleted the up-to-date answer, leaving the obsolete ones. [close review invalidated twice](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24014598/timeline).

Through some comments, I tried to convince some people to update the [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) tag wiki itself instead, as seen by [my many approved edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607508/revisions), but this practice of keeping the tag wiki always up-to-date ended up being [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19708129) by the community, and I refrained from updating the tag.

So I'm at a loss: there are too many random places where we can see the latest download locations for Xcode, and close reviews seem to often fail. Could we have some cleanup? And some guidance regarding if it fits best on a Question or on a Tag Wiki or nowhere at all?

<sup>* (blame me, I'm also in this revision log)</sup>

Comment: If this belongs anywhere on Stack Overflow, I think you were right in keeping it up to date on the tag wiki.

Comment: SO is trying to keep up with a moving target... that's not fair for a site that aims to be an authoritative source of information. Having to scramble at the beck and call of a third party is not fun at all. I think that the best place of keeping this information is in Apple's own knowledge base. If they want devs to register to download their stuff, they should also deal with the devs that doesn't want to.

Comment: (As indicated by the naked link, 4839526 has now been deleted. About 6 hours after this was posted.)

Answer (score 24):

Several thoughts, in no particular order

1. The reason we have Offsite Resources closure in the first place is that links [get stale really quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Download links are the bread of links: they go bad faster than normal links and require constant updates.
2. Worse, you promote the "Me too" answers. These are people who go "I also know the answer!" and so they post their answer at the bottom of page 2 every time there's a release.
3. Is Stack Overflow really the place to keep the links updated? Yes, we do try to help people with programming tools, but the problem I have with where to get the software downloaded from is partially explained by #1, but also because **we're potentially creating stale results in search engines**

   [image]

I'd normally say we need to remove all the questions (for instance [this one is worthless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions)), but apparently Apple likes to make you register to get to the download file (but doesn't do anything to restrict it to just logged-in devs), and thus, we get the rolling list of downloads for <s>the unwashed masses</s> people who don't want to register.

In all other cases, the version info and download links belong in the tag wiki (a lot of them already do) but, in this case, we already have

1. A collaborative locked question (with regular updates on a community wiki)
2. High Google rankings for the term

So everything else should be closed as a duplicate of [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file), or as requesting an off-site resource. We need to clean your list up to leave it with *just* that one question remaining.

Comment: That *locked* stuff smells. To be done correctly: remove question from author (it should be [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) question, not just some random noob who gets reputation for nothing), remove all deleted questions (it's looks afwul if you can see it) and make this feature **official** (so that anyone can demand it, otherwise it's pretty unfair exception).

Comment: @Sinatr It smells, but sometimes we leave things for historical reasons. Locks prevent new answers and let the community know this is an exception, not a rule.

Comment: *"people who don't want to register"* - not sure if this argument is valid, because clicking either of links shows authorization page. And if post is continuously updated - I am not sure "hystorical" reasons is a valid excuse anymore. Your screenshot and first link (unless google adds) is the right way to download the stuff. Btw, there is additional, perhaps quite useful information about which version is the last to support certain OS). That would make sense to keep, but not by letting crappy question/answer stay, but making a new good question and answer.

Comment: @Sinatr Just to be clear, I'm not advocating leaving them all up (heck, I just helped get the big worthless one deleted). But the locked one can stay. Asking it anew today would draw a closure. And all the other ones the OP linked are closed now too. And speaking from experience, having a defined dupe target would get future questions like this closed faster.

Answer (score 24):

Such questions should be deleted.

SO is not an authoritative source to answer questions like "Where do I download X". Google is one or perhaps someone's blog if official pages are too bad. But not SO.

Regarding tag wikis:

> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.

Overview is different from specific download instructions or any kind of instruction. At most the link to popular tutorial explaining those.

Comment: google can't be the *authorial* source, mind you. it'll only link to one.

Comment: @eis Strictly speaking, Google _could_ be the authorial source of, say, Android. (pedantry aside, though, you have a good point, in that it'd be more accurate to say you can Google for the correct source)

Answer (score 21):

Use both a tag wiki and a question that you can close others as duplicates of. Ideally, answer the question with a link *to the wiki*...

Wait, what? Heh... I'll explain.

Which tag wiki do you think gets the most views on Stack Overflow? Probably JavaScript, right? Most popular tag on the site? Or maybe Java or C#, the next two?

...nope. It's this one: [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). And it's *been* JSTL for years. Because the good JSTL folks [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/4928309#4928309) to [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593603/jstl-xmlns-namespace-differences-between-jsf-1-2-and-jsf-2-x) from [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags/2811676#2811676) answers. There are [372 links to the wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ftags%2Fjstl%2Finfo) on Stack Overflow, from answers to questions with hundreds of thousands of views... How many links are there to the xcode wiki? [Zero. Nada. None.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ftags%2Fxcode%2Finfo)

Tag wikis are a handy place to stash information that needs to be updated frequently *and* needs to be referenced frequently. **But they are not very discoverable**. Folks search for questions, not "[topic] wiki"; you *need* those questions to exist, or you'll just keep getting more questions.

So pick one, close the others as duplicates, and make sure to reference that wiki *from answers to questions where it's relevant* as often as you possibly can.

Comment: Why link from a canonical answer to the wiki and update the wiki, instead of just updating the canonical answer?

Comment: You can do both, @Stijn. The value of the wiki only appears when you're linking to it from *multiple* places: a "how to install" section of the wiki may be relevant to multiple questions about procurement, installation, etc. Alternately, a sufficiently thorough answer, if kept up to date, can serve this role so long as it too is crosslinked heavily.

Comment: In other words, Google thinks that the post is authoritative source due crosslinking. The only reason why tag wikis aren't authoritative is because no one links to them. If you want them to be discoverable, you need to link to them.

Answer (score 0):

Tag wikis are broken. They're completely invisible to the majority of users, because they don't show up in search results, can't be used as a duplicate or close reason, and I'm not even sure if they're reachable on the mobile site.

This means two things:

1. People won't find the link in the tag wiki, even if it's beautifully formatted and faithfully kept up to date.
2. People won't notice that the tag wiki is out of date, so it is more likely to go out of date than something that people are regularly finding.

If there is a Community Wiki reference answer which *is regularly updated* by interested users, that seems like the best place, and other questions can be closed as duplicates, as Machavity says. If there wasn't anybody willing / able to keep it up to date, it should probably be closed or even deleted.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if the downvotes are a) because people disagree with my assessment of tag wikis; b) because they disagree with some other part of it, or c) because they don't think this answers the question sufficiently.

Comment: Questions for which a question like these would work as a dupe target should be closed as _off topic_, not as dupes, IMO. Keeping around this questions is detrimental no matter if they are carefully maintained or not, as they end up serving as example of a valid question (highly upvoted at that) in the site, whereas they are not.

Comment: @yivi Thanks, that reasoning makes sense to me. There's a bit of a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" here - clearly, people will keep asking these questions *even if we delete the current ones*; but leaving them around may encourage people to ask *other similar questions*.