# A canonical answer is not actually canonical; what to do?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

C++ has this issue, which is called "[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)". It is a never-ending source for duplicate questions. It seems that we don't have a canonical answer for that. But worse, we have a [highly-upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/509868), which has "most vexing parse" in the title, but asks about a different thing (it asks about some corner case in the "most vexing parse" issue).

The problem is when someone asks a question, the answer to which is, "most vexing parse". People (who know the answer and want to mark as duplicate) naturally search for "most vexing parse", find a highly-upvoted question with answer, and mark as duplicate without reading. Because, honestly, if you know the answer to that mind-boggling issue, you don't want to read and understand the question and answer for 69th time in your life.

So, questions often get duplicate-closed with a link to a loosely-related and highly technical question and answer, leaving OPs scratching their heads and complaining about the injustice of it all.

Can we do anything constructive in this situation?

Comment: Change the title of the target to reflect what the question is actually about, that way, no one would be able to search for it.

Comment: Closing as dup is pointless.  Just post a comment "Google 'the most vexing parse'", vote as off-topic > typo and DV.

Comment: omg that language. No wonder the c++ tag is full of hate and madness.

Comment: @Braiam: Title of the linked question seems quite accurate already, people who are picking something with `T(())` in the title for a question that isn't about that -- should know better.

Comment: @BenVoigt no, it's not. The title should be "Why the common solution for the most versing parse doesn't work for using empty parenthesis instead of an object constructor?". Yeah, is more long, but we want titles to be descriptive.

Comment: @Braiam: Or probably "Why doesn't adding nested parentheses solve the most vexing parse in the zero argument case?" if your sole goal is to eliminate the code excerpt.  But why describing the code the long way may be more searchable, it is in no way more accurate.  And the question body should provide the searchability.  The current title is very descriptive -- and unambiguous, something that "the common solution" lacks.

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't that comment be against the  brand new Code of Conduct?

Comment: Just don't comment if you don't want to help.

Comment: By the way, Google also shows this Q&A with a misleading title for some reason. It just calls it "Most vexing parse" and the second part about `A a(());` is not shown. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwqCe.png I have no idea why Google might be doing this, but it makes any suggestions involving the post title more complicated.

Comment: @Radiodef google is just removing the unnecessary suffix after the colon.

Comment: @BenVoigt "if your sole goal is to eliminate the code excerpt" no, my sole purpose is that the question doesn't suck people into it, thinking it has the answer to their queries. Being more descriptive and precise allows just that.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, and the existing title is precise, and should not suck in people whose code has more than zero arguments.  The title you proposed is neither precise nor descriptive.

Comment: @BenVoigt are you serious? Have you looked at the list of questions pointing towards that one? Just look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30194685/792066) question! The answers doesn't match at all and a user with the gold badge couldn't recognize that the two questions aren't the same. [How much evidence do you need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1424510?lq=1)

Comment: @Braiam: I'm not saying the status quo is good enough, I'm saying your proposed title makes matters worse.  As did the misguided edit that I just rolled back.  "Two pairs of parenthesis" covers `T t(())` but also `T t((a))`... it would make improper duplicate marking *more* prevalent, not less.

Comment: @BenVoigt I invite you then to write a better one. I don't think mine is a good title, but at least is not deceptive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Although people are quibbling about the particular example C++ question in your question here, the general question *"A canonical answer is not actually canonical; what to do?"* still stands.

I believe @Braiam's comment *"Change the title of the target to reflect what the question is actually about, that way, no one would be able to search for it"* is generally the right approach.

If a question is really more specific than the title suggests, change the title to be more specific.

Comment with a link to a/the more general question, or maybe ask and answer the general question yourself if there isn't already one.

Comment: In other words, artificially butcher the title to work around oddities in search engine behaviors and user search patterns. This isn't an issue with the post title but an issue with how search engines interpret user searches and how they present results to searchers. See Radiodef's comment above.

Comment: @BoltClock - Maybe it's not clear in my post, but no I don't mean "artificially butcher the title". My thought is to _correct_ the title to be more specific and more accurate, so it reflects the actual question asked and not the broader question such a title may imply. I _do_ think Radiodef's comment is pertinent.

Comment: The title doesn't need to be corrected. The title needs to be minced in a way that works around how search engines match search keywords to page titles (and even then there is only so much the author can do to that end). You can write the most precise title in the world with all the right keywords and it would *still* turn up for a lot of the wrong searches and few of the right ones. If you do manage to make it less discoverable, you do so not just for the searchers it's not intended for, but also the ones it *is* intended for.

Comment: @BoltClock you know what else the search engines doesn't show in the top searches? Pages without crosslinking. You know what this question have? [Tons of crosslinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1424510). You know how the search engine determines the relevance of a page? Crosslinking. The title alone is not to workaround the search engine, is to prevent users from being confused by the results the search engine gives them, since it considers the question too relevant given the amount of backlinks it has. [Consult Shog about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472)

Comment: @Braiam: So by your own admission editing the title is going to do *nothing* to alleviate the question being ranked up due to all its crosslinking or make it harder to find. Why suggest editing it, then? What is lacking in the title? It seems specific as it is. And yet still people are being misdirected to it and mistaking it for an appropriate dupe target. That's not the fault of the title, at all.

Comment: @BoltClock no, actually it would alleviate the problem **by not allowing it to continue growing**. If you modify the title, people that find it wouldn't add more crosslinks to it since the title wouldn't match what they think the question would be about. Why that wouldn't alleviate the problem? Now, to reverse the effects of the problem, we only need gold badge owners to figure out another target and change all those questions that doesn't ask what the target is about. Think outside the box, don't be dismissing of crazy solutions to deceptively simple problems.

Comment: @Braiam: Then my point about the title actually needing to be stripped of its meaning to make the question harder to find stands, since even with its existing meaning readers are *still* misinterpreting it and misusing it as a dupe target. I don't disagree with editing the title this way, but I disagree with presenting it under the guise of "making the title more accurate", because actually making it more accurate would be futile at best and counterproductive at worst.

Comment: @BoltClock no, it wouldn't be *"harder to find"*, it would be **"harder to find when that's not what you are looking for"**. Is a subtle difference but very important. That's what I'm all about.

Comment: @BoltClock "making it more accurate would be futile at best and counterproductive at worst" what?! Seriously? Counterproductive in what circumstance?