# Can we restore answers with documentation links, expanding which documentation these links point to?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7156908/2945027) on the documentation where to get the information for the `<*mmintrin.h>` headers. It is a legitimate question, and some of the C++ compilers ship with these headers, but there isn't any satisfactory documentation on it.

Some answers were deleted, presumably due to being link-only answers. In particular, an answer pointing to [Intel® Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html).

On one hand, these are link-only answers, with being subject to link rot.

On the other hand, they do answer the question "where is some documentation?", that is not obvious for some people (+46 vote on the top of these answers is a clear indication).

Can we restore these answers, and, to prevent links instability, describe more where these links point to, so in case of link rot, new locations of these resources can be easily found?

Comment: "Can we restore these answers, and, to prevent links instability, describe more where these links point to, so in case of link rot, new locations of these resources can be easily found?" Is there any reason why you don't post such a proper answer yourself?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, that's a possible implementation of "restoring". But if it is in principle considered wrong, my answer should be deleted too, so I'd like to clarify it before going ahead.

Comment: I'm confused, the content of that answer is still present in the first comment to the question. That comment has not been deleted in almost 10 years. Why does it need to be an answer?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that's correct. But the comment is far less visible. (And it probably can be suddenly deleted too)

Comment: I would say it's far more visible than a deleted answer... :P

Comment: You ask about *answers*, but the **question** itself seems to be **off-topic** as a request for off-site resources (documentation). According to the history, the question has already been closed once. Probably, before discussing possible answers, it should be a discussion about validity of the question itself.

Comment: Well for one it is a double whammy of super triggers. An offsite resource request and a would-be link-only answer. Oof, good luck with that one. You can argue that obscure documentation makes for valuable questions, but when is documentation obscure? How do you prove that it is and not simply people being too lazy to search properly? It is hard to draw the line, and I believe it is for that reason that these rules are followed with zero tolerance. It is better to have zero tolerance than complete randomness in how rules are applied.

Comment: (that being said... why was the question reopened?)

Comment: @Gimby Because the OP (of this meta question) and two others voted to reopen it :).

Comment: @Gimby, the question was reopened because I nominated it for reopen, and someone else supported it. Good point about avoiding rules to be applied randomly, though. I believe this would be a loss to delete this Q&A, but maybe it indeed should be done towards following consistent rules

Comment: @HereticMonkey, update on the comment, the link there was expired, so the answer had a value because the link was up to date.

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to shove these on the tag wiki?

Comment: @Braiam, these links are already in [tag:sse] wiki (and also somewhere among the [tag:x86] links. Not sure though how much tag wiki is visible.

Comment: Not all useful things belong on the site. "Useful" is not a sufficient reason.

Comment: They are visible, but [you have to use them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/792066)

Comment: @Braiam, good point; added a link to tag wiki to that question. Now there are [25 links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ftags%2Fsse%2Finfo) to it.

Comment: I converted your answer to a comment because it's asking for official sources. An SO tag wiki is not that, even if it might be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### The answers have been undeleted.

These answers were deleted by a moderator in response to NAA flags. However, they do answer the question which was asked, which is asking for resources, so I've undeleted them. I've also edited the question to make it clear that it's asking for the location of an official reference, for which there is [an exception to requests for off-site resources being off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/3773011).

[I also closed as a resource request a different old question asking for tutorials which was linked from a deleted answer on that question, which has been previously converted to a comment.]

##### Another time, please raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag.

Another time, if you feel something deleted by a moderator should be undeleted, please first raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag and explain the issue. The reason to raise the flag is that only moderators can undelete posts which were deleted by a moderator, so it's impossible for non-moderators to actually accomplish what you desire. Thus, if you only post on Meta Stack Overflow (MSO), you're basically just *hoping* a moderator will happen to see your MSO question and asking the users frequenting MSO to spend time on something they can't do anything about. If your "in need of moderator intervention" flag is declined, then it's quite reasonable to bring this type of issue to MSO for review.

Comment: Is this why the word "find" was dropped from the 3rd party resource close reason?

Comment: @BSMP IIRC, that disappeared in the edits by SE staff which were intended to make the close reasons more "welcoming".