# What's the best way to post a "How to ask a good question?" article for a specific subject?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, which I suspect most people haven't.  What I'm wondering is what is the best way to provide information about asking a question about a specific subject.

My example is someone asking a question about [cognos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cognos), [cognos-bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cognos-bi), [cognos-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cognos-11), or [cognos-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cognos-10).  I believe a good Cognos question includes some or all of the elements below, based on the nature of the problem.  (And the article may not be complete, so it should allow editing.)

**Where would information like this be posted?**

---

**Asking a good Cognos question**

There is already good information about [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on StackOverflow.  This article supplements that with information specifically for Cognos users.

In order to attract experienced developers, you'll want to ask question that provide enough information, and don't expect the answerer to do all of the heavy lifting.  When developing a question regarding IBM Cognos Analytics/Business Intelligence, consider the following items to include.

An example of the problem using the samples data (probably using the "GO sales (query)" package).

- Including screen captures, sample data, or sample code from your actual system could compromise data security.
- Other Cognos users probably have access to the samples data.  They do not have access to your data.
- Using the samples can demonstrate a problem and prove it is a Cognos problem and not related to your data.

A report spec demonstrating the problem and the attempt to solve it (if the question is about how to code or configure a specific item in the Cognos UI)

- Report specs can be posted on https://pastebin.com/ so anyone interested in attempting to answer the question doesn't need to do the heavy lifting.

SQL:  Sample data and query logic

- If you're using a reporting tool (like Cognos) to develop reports that access data in SQL Server, Oracle, or related database platforms, it seems reasonable to assume you have a basic knowledge of SQL and query logic.  If you do not have basic SQL skills, there are many basic SQL tutorials available online.
- It is often simpler to express your query logic question in SQL terms rather than in Cognos terms.  Even if you have trouble expressing your question this way, realize that it may be easier to express the answer this way, especially if you have not provided a report spec using the samples data.
- Sample data should be included as a link to a spreadsheet or SQL `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.
- Sites like https://dbfiddle.uk/ provide a way to save, edit, and run SQL code.  This can make communication and solution development easier.

Comment: "A sample using the samples", is *samples* a well-known term within Cognos? If not, you can just use Stack Overflow's `[mre]` magic link. I'm having difficulties with suggesting pastebin or dbfiddle to post off-site code. Normally, we require *everything* to be in the question itself, i.e. one should be able to answer the question without having to access off-site links. Links may of course be provided as references or supportive material though

Comment: You're commenting on the instructions, not the question that I posted here.  But thanks. 
 You're right.  I use "samples" to mean two different things.  It's funny:  In the `cognos` wiki update (so, revised after this post), I actually say how important vocabulary is.  As for off-site links, have you seen the `sql` questions?  If you're not using dbfiddle, you're doing it wrong.  Not using dbfiddle puts a much bigger load on the answerer.  Maybe someday StackOverflow will have that functionality built in.

Comment: I just created a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831814/information-repeating-on-subsequent-pages) and tried to follow my own instructions.  SO didn't like the link to pastebin without code in the question.  The problem I see here is this isn't code that the developer typically edits directly.  It's an XML document that is edited through the Report Authoring GUI.  I prefer pastebin because this is really for a copy-paste operation to get into the GUI.  Code just bloats the question.

Answer (score 12):

I'm of the impression that this would be suitable for the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cognos/info).  There's some [prior art](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) in that tag wikis have been used as a way to communicate the best way for people to ask questions about a specific subject.

Comment: Have you ever seen anyone actually look in the tag wiki for this information? Why would this be preferred over the Meta Q&A, which can at least be easily linked, edited, etc.?

Comment: This is sadly true. The C++ Tag Wiki used to have a small list of commonly asked questions with links to the answers and a request that the question not be re-asked. Some of the questions got asked a couple times a day anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray A tag wiki is a collection of tag usage rules and information there as a resource to _veteran users_. It's a place where veteran users can go to find close reasons, canonical dupes, commonly used external resources and so on. Then link these to new users. I don't see why it would be any harder to link to a tag wiki than a meta post. On the contrary, it's hopeless to find anything on meta unless you have it bookmarked.

Comment: trusted user - Milestone privilege awarded at 20,000 reputation.  Delightful.  At this rate, that should only take about 40 years.

Comment: @dougp welcome to the club :) the tag system is the most underdeveloped features on the network with some of the most baffling decisions on privileges I've ever seen. In 3K rep you will be able to review wiki suggestions and you already can unilaterally edit every post however you see fit. But god forbid you edit a single tag wiki by yourself :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The only user with over 20k that has ever answered a Cognos question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883376/how-do-i-catch-javascript-functions-that-are-being-called/3883429#3883429) doesn't even use Cognos.  The [tag:cognos] tag was added incorrectly.  The question is about how to watch JavaScript in action in a browser, and is over 10 years old.  Nobody over 5k has answered a Cognos question in over 7 years.

Comment: CodyGray and Lundin:  It looks like adding to a tag wiki is "a" way, but may not be the best way?  I assume veteran users already know how to ask questions.  If new users don't visit the tag wiki (Clicking the tag does a search for items with that tag - not the tag wiki - and the Learn more... link at the top and the View tag link in the tooltip are subtle) that may not be the place to put this content.  But I don't see how it could hurt.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, [Shog already showed us the way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/792066)

Comment: @dougp you might be surprised. This stuff kind of sneaks up on you. I thought the site broke one day when I pitched a duplicate and hammered the question shut. I was in the middle of writing a bug report when someone congratulated me on getting a new badge.

Comment: [Could we add a tag-specific MRE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423)